# SRAM i3 coaster brake only activating after multiple turns backwards

Tags: brakes, internally-geared-hub, sram, coaster

My son's bike has a SRAM i3 internal gear + coaster brake hub. It has recently started sometimes only activating the coaster brake after backpedalling a good one or two full revolutions. When in this situation, it sounds somewhat clunky or grindy when the brake finally activates. However, sometimes, it kicks in straight away. I haven't found a solid pattern to when it works and doesn't, but it seems that the brake is more reliable in gear 1 than in gear 3, though I might be wrong about this. Can this adjusted/fixed, or do I need to replace the mechanism?

EDIT: After experimenting with the brakes and gearing with the bike in a stand (previously I had been trying while riding it) it seems that in gear 1, the brake always works fine. In gear 3, it requires almost a full rotation backwards before the gear engages. While in gear 2, it's somewhere between - about half a rotation.

Comment: Is the "arm" from the hub tightly attached to both hub and frame?

Comment: the brake arm is tightly attached to the chainstay. As for the hub, I can't tell as I haven't got a thin spanner as large as the nut that's there, but there is a locknut, and it seems tight, but I can't be certain. However, I would be surprised if it had come loose on its own as I haven't touched it, and it's been running fine for ages.

Comment: How much mileage has this gearbox done in its life.  How long/far since the last oil change ?

Comment: I bought it second hand, so don't know the previous history, but it's a kid's bike, so it won't be massive mileage. Since we've had it, it's done less that 1000km. Never had an oil change/service since I've had it, so I suppose that's what I'll look at doing.

Comment: I have the same hub, and the same problem. After 6 years of no problems. Btw. these hubs don't need oil replacement.

Answer (score 4):

[SRAM recalled 7,700 of these hubs](https://www.bicycling.com/news/a26521411/sram-recall-internal-gear-hubs/) due to brake failure in 2019.
Evidently the brake pawls were not lubricated properly.

> According to the company, some of the affected hubs may have been manufactured with grease that gets sticky over time, especially if the bike sits unused for a while or is stored in a hot area. When the grease becomes sticky, the brake pawls in the hub can fail to engage.

Further

> The recall applies to all bikes with this cruiser brake model that do not have independent front brakes.

The logic appears to be that if you have a front brake your hub does not need to be recalled.

According to the SRAM manual for this hub there are no user serviceable parts.

> Only a qualified bike dealer should perform any necessary work on the gear hub, shifter, and brakes.
> [SRAM i-Motion 3 User Manual](https://www.servicearchive.sram.com/sites/default/files/techdocs/iMOTION_3_Ins_E_6_06.pdf#:%7E:text=Your%20SRAM%20i-MOTION%203%20System%20is%20almost%20maintenance-free.,nice%20time%20and%20enjoy%20your%20SRAM%20i-MOTION%203.)

The manual says that "the brake jacket has to be lubricated with special grease. This work must be performed by a qualified bike dealer"

First I'd read the manual and make sure everything is adjusted correctly.
If that does not work then you can choose between:

- Fixing it yourself
- Finding someone else to fix it
- Replacing the wheel

The easy way to get rear brakes might be to add a hand brake to this bike if it will take one.

Comment: Note that it's lethal folly to ride a bike with only a single functioning brake. Especially hand operated brakes can and do break, and you don't want to be on a bike where the one and only brake fails you. As such, I see the part about not recalling bikes with a hand brake with disgust.